# pass ajax response (json)data in php

Tags: mysql, ajax, json, database

So, I am stuck here and feel like banging my head.
My problem is I query a database by ajax and returned its response in json form. Now I have this response in the form of javascript variable but I want to pass it to a php variable for further use.
How can I do that ??

```
function getJson(url){
        return JSON.parse($.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url: url,
            dataType:'json',
            global:false,
            async:false,
            success: function(data){
                return data;
            }
        }).responseText);
    }
```

Here how do I pass data to php ??

Comment: Why would you hand a value back to JS, only to then try and send it back to the server again? That makes little sense to me. Do what you have to do with the value on the server in the first place, _before_ sending out an answer for the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

```
FIrstly I gave you -1 for not learning the basics!
- You can send client values to server (php) as querystring 
  example: /server_link?json=JSON_VAL
  (not recommended for whole json string) 

- Send it as post body (look for jquery ajax post) and parse it with php json library.
- if you have just single level json ({name:'John', sname:'Smith)} you can send it to php server(as mentioned before ajax post) and read as request variable in php ($_POST, $_...).

As I never programmed in php you'll have to do it you're self.
```

A again: LEARN THE BASICS (client side, server side, post, get,...).